# Event log monitoring

Tags: monitoring, event-log

I need to monitor my Windows Server event logs so that I know if there is a problem with any of my ASP.Net websites (IIS errors, windows login errors etc) - errors that would end up in the event log rather than being handled by my application's error logging.

Has anyone had any experience of [GFI Events Manager](http://www.gfi.com/eventsmanager/) or [Event Sentry](http://www.eventsentry.com/)? Is there anything better on the market?

Answer (score 2):

I currently use EventSentry and I have to say I am very happy with it. I get an email when my backups don't run, the reports are helpful and my experience with the support staff has been great. In my case, EventSentry was much cheaper than GFI and offered the value I needed.

Comment: +1, We use it too. GFI was just too expensive and much more than we actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this tool, but Microsoft' System Center Operations Manager (used to be called Microsoft Operations Manager) should do all of that.

[System Center Operations Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/opsmgr/default.mspx?sess=296d9b4b1d52c17152baa2806e58dd78)

Answer (score 0):

[PA Server Monitor](http://www.poweradmin.com/servermonitor) can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the budget is tight, or you want to customize the solution a bit more, there are [.NET libraries available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) that would allow you to write your own web app or console app to retrieve/update the details out of the event log.

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Host Monitor](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/) by KS-Soft is a monitoring program that can send you alerts based on event log messages.